# How to properly add multiple child columns to a pandas dataframe - KeyError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

EDIT:

This seems like a simpler formulation of the question:

I have the following line of code:

`imu_data.loc[:, idx[1, 'Ax', 'delta']] = 1`

And this works as intended, creating a new 'delta' subcolumn under 1 > 'Ax' and setting its values to 1.

I can do the following:

```
    for i in range(1, 7):
        imu_data.loc[:, idx[i, 'Ax', 'delta']] = 1
```

And it works as intended, creating the new 'delta' column for each number.

However, when I try the following:

`imu_data.loc[:, idx[1:6, 'Ax', 'delta']] = 1`

Which, from my understanding, should be the same as the above, I get the following error: `KeyError: 'delta'`

So, it looks like if I am using a range, I'm not allowed to create a new column.

Is there any way around this, or am I forced to loop through all numbers 1 to 7?

Comment: Create a smaller simple dataframe with let's six columns, then show the desired output for that smaller dataframe.

Comment: So you changed the whole question ??